# Are Labyrinth and Pan's Labyrinth based on some myth/legend?

Tags: plot-explanation, pans-labyrinth, labyrinth

Labyrinth (1986) and Pan's Labyrinth (2005) have a similar plot in that
a young girl 'loses' her baby brother to 'monsters' and must get him back.

Is this based on some myth, fable, or legend from some culture?

Comment: Been reading around,  and these films seem to play on the folklore of the changeling - but I'm not finding much where an elder sibling is quested to rescue a baby/infant

Answer (score 24):

Yes, **in Greek mythology, the original labyrinth was built by [Daedalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daedalus)**, on Crete, to keep the Minotaur (half man, half bull) imprisoned. This is likely where the idea comes from that labyrinths contain monsters.

King Minos, for whom Daedalus had made the structure, later had him imprisoned in the labyrinth instead, and this is whence his famous son Icarus fled using the wings made of feathers and wax his father crafted for him.

**The archetype of the young girl could be based on [Ariadne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariadne)**, the girl who fell in love with the hero Theseus, who was to kill the Minotaur and thus ventured into the maze. She gave Theseus a ball of string so he would be able to find his way back.

However, both [Jim Henson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(1986_film)#Influences) and [del Toro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%27s_Labyrinth#Influences) (the directors of *Labyrinth* and *El Laberinto del Fauno* [the better title], respectively) were **influenced by many fairy tales and stories of young girls ending up in fantastical realms - Carroll's *Alice in Wonderland* in particular**.
Ofelia shares her name with the Shakespearean character from *Hamlet*, but it has been pointed out that she has more in common with the titular character. <sup>1</sup>

That Sarah Williams has to save her half-brother in *Labyrinth* was based on Maurice Sendak's [*Outside over There*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outside_Over_There), but where the subplot of Ofelia bringing her baby half-brother into the labyrinth comes from is a little harder to pinpoint. Del Toro kept notes on what would become *El Laberinto* for over a decade, perfecting concepts for monsters and figuring out all the details, and the influences and personal inventions will make this extremely difficult to figure out.
Nevertheless, the narrative has a lot of (anti-)Catholic, mythical, and mystical undertones, and the sacrifice that Ofelia is asked to make towards the end could very well be a direct reference to the blood sacrifice made for the lives of others (but also the blood that necessarily needs to flow for new life to occur <sup>2</sup> ).

1: [Pan's Labyrinth, A Critical Analysis](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a4f36c48c56a8ac7b9cb7fa/t/5a6edc5571c10beb5b38e61a/1517214830770/PansLabyrinth.pdf) by Safia Southey.

2: Many examples of this interpretation can be found [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=pan%27s%20labyrinth%20ovaries%20uterus).

Comment: Funnily enough, the classical [geometric pattern known as a labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth#Labyrinth_as_pattern) would be entirely pointless for this purpose, since it is a single (very, very winding) path.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins But those are representations. The idea was entirely based on keeping the Minotaur inside. But with a bull's head, who knows how intelligent the half-beast actually was.

Comment: @Joachim he might not be intelligent, but we know he'd be persistent :)

Comment: @GeoffAtkins At least in modern terms, that's the defining distinction between a labyrinth and a maze.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question regarding an older child rescuing a baby/infant sibling as a trope.

Comment: I am not sure that the young girl is Ariadne since Ariadne was simply helping the hero. She is Theseus but transformed into a helpless girl, because it is scarier than a powerful man (the movies' genre is fantasy horror, not adventure). And I guess the movies are a mix of several myths (Orpheus going to hell to find a loved one for example)

Comment: In the myth, the Minoans kidnapped (or tithed) young women to imprison in the Labyrinth to feed the Minotaur. That's the crucial part.

Comment: @Taladris The idea that navigating the labyrinth is based on Theseus' descent is fascinating, but ultimately this is Campbell's 'crossing of the threshold', and has many antecedents. That the young girl is Theseus is maybe more compelling, but doesn't account for the simple fact that here she's a young girl. Maybe Ariadne and Theseus have been combined, but, ultimately, both plots are no mere rehashes of any of the Greek myths involved, so looking for all answers in one place will yield poor results.

Comment: @OrangeDog Why is that the crucial part?

Comment: Because girls/children being captured in a labyrinth is what the question is about...